# Facebook Graph API always return bad request error when exception

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bad-request

When I use the Graph API Explore to call API
It return an error with code and a clear message

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 467,
      "fbtrace_id": "EoVgj1S1wGM"
   }
}
```

but when I call the API by WebRequest, It just return an exception with message:

```
The remote server returned an error: Bad Request (400)
```

This is my code:

```
try
      {
          var facebookBusinessAccountId =
                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook_business_account_id"];
          facebookRestUrl += "&access_token=" + acct.AccessToken;

          facebookRestUrl = facebookRestUrl.Replace("{0}", facebookBusinessAccountId);

          var request = WebRequest.Create(facebookRestUrl);
          request.Method = method;
          request.ContentType = "application/json";

          var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
          var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());

          responseString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

          return responseString;
      }
catch (Exception e)
          {
              throw e;
          }
```

This is full url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/myBusinessID?fields=business_discovery.username(bong__collection){biography,id,ig_id,followers_count,follows_count,media_count,name,profile_picture_url,username,website}&access_token=EAAJJsScwhdEBAKR46qyJb7bMs9jcUqfK3ZCr...
```

Could anyone help me get full the error content as Graph API Explore?
Thanks!